# How to test if element(tag) rendered with jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I cannot understand how properly test in element is rendered or not. I wrote such a test:

```
const props = {
  type: 'test_plan',
  renewal: '25.06.2019',
  subscriptionName: 'Test',
};
test('test component elements render', () => {

     const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
     console.log(wrapper.debug())
     expect(wrapper.find('.link')).to.have.lengthOf(0);
     expect(wrapper.find('type')).to.have.lengthOf(1);

    });
```

This what I have in the console when debug component:

```
<div className="wrapper">
        <div className="mobile">
          <h3>
            Test
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div className="inner">
          <h3>
            Test
          </h3>
          <div className="type">
            <h4>
              Test Type 1
            </h4>
            <span>

              25.06.2019
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and this is error that I have `Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`

How properly test if element in component rendered or no???

Comment: Have you tried `wrapper.find('.link').length).toEqual(0)`

Comment: @Rajesh yes that's work. Could you explain why this works and mine not?

Comment: I guess yours is not working because you are trying to do `to.have` operation on non-existing item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.to.have.lengthOf` is an [assertion from `Chai`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_lengthof).

So you can either require `expect` from `Chai` and use the `Chai` assertion:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

const expect = require('chai').expect;  // <= use expect from Chai

const Component = () => (<div><div className="type"></div></div>);

test('test component elements render', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
  expect(wrapper.find('.link')).to.have.lengthOf(0);  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.find('.type')).to.have.lengthOf(1);  // Success!
});
```

...or you can use the [`.toHaveLength`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber) assertion included in `Jest`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

const Component = () => (<div><div className="type"></div></div>);

test('test component elements render', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
  expect(wrapper.find('.link')).toHaveLength(0);  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.find('.type')).toHaveLength(1);  // Success!
});
```